# Adding a second UNION causing error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query I am working on that is returning correctly.

```
DECLARE @theItewId VARCHAR(100) = (SELECT item_id 
   FROM   ndc_attr 
   WHERE  attr_val = '00310072010'); 

SELECT nr.item_id, 
       nr.field_id, 
       nr.attr_val, 
       nr.upd_dtt, 
       nr.upd_usr, 
       nr.item_id, 
       1 AS counting, 
       nr.field_id 
FROM   ndc_attr nr 
WHERE  item_id = @theItewId 
       AND field_id IN ( 69, 144, 150, 148, 170 ) 
UNION ALL 
SELECT TOP 1 @theItewId          AS item_id, 
             418                 AS field_id, 
             nr.contract_num_val AS attr_val, 
             CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   AS upd_dtt, 
             '-1'                AS upd_usr, 
             '-1'                AS item_id, 
             '-1'                AS counting, 
             '-1'                AS field_id 
FROM   contract_ndc_brg nr 
WHERE  ndc_id = '00310072010' 
ORDER  BY upd_dtt DESC
```

But when I try to add another UNION ALL I am getting an error and don't understand why.

```
DECLARE @theItewId VARCHAR(100) = (SELECT item_id 
   FROM   ndc_attr 
   WHERE  attr_val = '00310072010'); 

SELECT nr.item_id, 
       nr.field_id, 
       nr.attr_val, 
       nr.upd_dtt, 
       nr.upd_usr, 
       nr.item_id, 
       1 AS counting, 
       nr.field_id 
FROM   ndc_attr nr 
WHERE  item_id = @theItewId 
       AND field_id IN ( 69, 144, 150, 148, 170 ) 
UNION ALL 
SELECT TOP 1 @theItewId          AS item_id, 
             418                 AS field_id, 
             nr.contract_num_val AS attr_val, 
             CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   AS upd_dtt, 
             '-1'                AS upd_usr, 
             '-1'                AS item_id, 
             '-1'                AS counting, 
             '-1'                AS field_id 
FROM   contract_ndc_brg nr 
WHERE  ndc_id = '00310072010' 
ORDER  BY upd_dtt DESC 
UNION ALL 
SELECT TOP 1 @theItewId        AS item_id, 
             981               AS field_id, 
             nr.quote_price        AS attr_val, 
             CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS upd_dtt, 
             '-1'              AS upd_usr, 
             '-1'              AS item_id, 
             '-1'              AS counting, 
             '-1'              AS field_id 
FROM   contract_ndc_brg nr 
WHERE  ndc_id = '00310072010' 
ORDER  BY upd_dtt DESC
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Edit:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure USP_ENTY_ATTR_GET_BY_ATTR_VALS, Line 151
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNION'.

Comment: An error, you say? There are a lot of those. Which one is yours?

Comment: Hmm, I though I added it. I moment.

Comment: I found the error! I pulled it out into a quote block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you can't do an ORDER BY in one of your UNIONS. You can do this, but you need to encapsulate the statement in a subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT nr.item_id, 
       nr.field_id, 
       nr.attr_val, 
       nr.upd_dtt, 
       nr.upd_usr, 
       nr.item_id, 
       1 AS counting, 
       nr.field_id 
FROM   ndc_attr nr 
WHERE  item_id = @theItewId 
       AND field_id IN ( 69, 144, 150, 148, 170 ) ) as t1
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT TOP 1 @theItewId          AS item_id, 
             418                 AS field_id, 
             nr.contract_num_val AS attr_val, 
             CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   AS upd_dtt, 
             '-1'                AS upd_usr, 
             '-1'                AS item_id, 
             '-1'                AS counting, 
             '-1'                AS field_id 
FROM   contract_ndc_brg nr 
WHERE  ndc_id = '00310072010' 
ORDER  BY upd_dtt DESC ) as t2
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT TOP 1 @theItewId        AS item_id, 
             981               AS field_id, 
             nr.quote_price        AS attr_val, 
             CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS upd_dtt, 
             '-1'              AS upd_usr, 
             '-1'              AS item_id, 
             '-1'              AS counting, 
             '-1'              AS field_id 
FROM   contract_ndc_brg nr 
WHERE  ndc_id = '00310072010' 
ORDER  BY upd_dtt DESC ) as t3
```

Answer (score 2):

ORDER BY must go only once and at the bottom of your query. You have repeated this line:

`ORDER  BY upd_dtt DESC`

which is causing the error